# Dynamically added ImageButton Command event not firing until second click

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, page-lifecycle

I have a page where I'm adding ImageButtons dynamically. I first set the `OnClientClick` of the buttons to simply show a popup of the image enlarged and return false for no postback.

I have a button on the page to set the "primary image" so when this button is clicked I set a property called `_IsSettingPrimaryPhotoMode = true`, call the function to recreate the ImageButtons, and when creating the ImageButtons if this property is true instead of adding an `OnClientClick`, I hook up a `CommandEventHandler` so I can tell which button was clicked by reading the `CommandArgument`.

The problem is the event handler won't fire on the first click of the image but only on the second click and thereafter. I've also moved the code from `Page_Load` to `OnInit` and I load the ImageButtons on every postback.

I save the `_IsSettingPrimaryPhotoMode` to the `Session`.

```
private bool _IsSettingPrimaryPhotoMode {
    get {
        bool result = false;

        if(Session[ConstantsWeb.Session.IS_DELETE_IMAGE_MODE] != null) {
            result = Convert.ToBoolean(Session[ConstantsWeb.Session.IS_SETTING_PRIMARY_IMAGE_MODE]);
        }

        return result;
    }
    set {
        Session[ConstantsWeb.Session.IS_SETTING_PRIMARY_IMAGE_MODE] = value;
    }
}
```

The page OnInit

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnInit(e);

        if(!IsPostBack) {
            _IsSettingPrimaryPhotoMode = false;
        }

        _LoadGalleryImages();
    }
}
```

The _LoadGalleryImages method

```
private void _LoadGalleryImages() {
    PhotoGalleryImageCollection images = PhotoGalleryImages.GetPhotoGalleryImages();

    foreach(PhotoGalleryImage image in images) {
        ImageButton displayImage = new ImageButton();
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panelPhotoContainer.Controls.Add(panel);
        displayImage.ImageUrl = "some URL";

        if(!_IsSettingPrimaryPhotoMode) {
            displayImage.OnClientClick = "showPopup(); return false;";
        }
        else {
            displayImage.Command += new CommandEventHandler(displayImage_Command);
            displayImage.CommandName = "ImageButton" + image.PhotoGalleryImageId.ToString();
            displayImage.CommandArgument = image.PhotoGalleryImageId.ToString();
        }

        panel.Controls.Add(displayImage);
    }
}
```

btnSetPrimaryPhoto_Click

```
protected void btnSetPrimaryPhoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // if I don't call this, duplicate controls will be added since they were added
    // from OnInit calling _LoadGalleryImages();
    panelPhotoContainer.Controls.Clear();
    _IsSettingPrimaryPhotoMode = true;
    // reload since _IsSettingPrimaryPhotoMode has now changed
    _LoadGalleryImages();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to add this code as well and see if it will correct your issue displayImage.Command -= new CommandEventHandler(displayImage_Command);

Comment: Why are you calling _LoadGalleryImages() in button click and another event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@swannee
Actually, your method did work after I thought more about it. I do now call _LoadGalleryImages on every OnInit. I realize this is a lot of duplicate code that could be consolidated.

New _LoadGalleryImages

```
private void _LoadGalleryImages() {
    PhotoGalleryImageCollection images = PhotoGalleryImages.GetPhotoGalleryImages();

    foreach(PhotoGalleryImage image in images) {
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panelPhotoContainer.Controls.Add(panel);

        ImageButton displayImage = new ImageButton();
        panel.Controls.Add(displayImage);
        displayImage.ID = string.Format("ImageButton{0}", image.PhotoGalleryImageId);
        displayImage.ImageUrl = "Some URL";
        displayImage.AlternateText = displayImage.ToolTip = image.ImageName;

        if(!_IsSettingPrimaryPhotoMode) {
            displayImage.OnClientClick = "showPopup(); return false;";
        }
        else {
            // handles the image button command wireup
            displayImage.Command += new CommandEventHandler(displayImage_Command);
            displayImage.CommandArgument = image.PhotoGalleryImageId.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I added a new method as you suggested to find the controls since they've already been created in OnInit and I just need to find them after the button click and clear the OnClientClick.

```
private void _LoadSelectPrimaryImages() {
    PhotoGalleryImageCollection images = PhotoGalleryImages.GetPhotoGalleryImages();

    foreach(PhotoGalleryImage image in images) {
        Control control = panelPhotoContainer.FindControl(string.Format("ImageButton{0}", image.PhotoGalleryImageId));

        if(control != null) {
            ImageButton displayImage = (ImageButton)control;
            displayImage.OnClientClick = "";
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a cancel button to return the image buttons to the way they were before to show the popup.

```
private void _ResetGalleryImages() {
    PhotoGalleryImageCollection images = PhotoGalleryImages.GetPhotoGalleryImages(_photoGalleryId, false, true);

    foreach(PhotoGalleryImage image in images) {
        Control control = panelPhotoContainer.FindControl(string.Format("ImageButton{0}", image.PhotoGalleryImageId));

        if(control != null) {
            ImageButton displayImage = (ImageButton)control;
            displayImage.ImageUrl = "Original URL";
            displayImage.OnClientClick = "showPopup(); return false;";
        }
    }
}
```

and two page button clicks

```
protected void btnSetPrimaryPhoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    _IsSettingPrimaryPhotoMode = true;
    _LoadSelectPrimaryImages();
}
```

```
protected void btnCancelSetPrimaryPhoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    _IsSettingPrimaryPhotoMode = false;
    _ResetGalleryImages();
}
```

Someone said in a response earlier...looks like the response was removed...to clear the controls in _LoadGalleryImages such as:

```
private void _LoadGalleryImages() {
    panelPhotoContainer.Controls.Clear();
    PhotoGalleryImageCollection images = PhotoGalleryImages.GetPhotoGalleryImages();

    foreach(PhotoGalleryImage image in images) {
        ImageButton displayImage = new ImageButton();
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panelPhotoContainer.Controls.Add(panel);
        displayImage.ImageUrl = "some URL";

        if(!_IsSettingPrimaryPhotoMode) {
            displayImage.OnClientClick = "showPopup(); return false;";
        }
        else {
            displayImage.Command += new CommandEventHandler(displayImage_Command);
            displayImage.CommandName = "ImageButton" + image.PhotoGalleryImageId.ToString();
            displayImage.CommandArgument = image.PhotoGalleryImageId.ToString();
        }

        panel.Controls.Add(displayImage);
    }
}
```

which also works but I think that may be more inefficient than your method, @swannee. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It has to be something related to the initial event wireup because the problem only happens the first time.  What's different about that time is that _LoadGalleryImages is called twice (once in the init and once in the button click event handler) so I think that something is not getting cleaned up there when you clear the container panel and call _LoadGalleryImages again in the button's click handler.

Why not try this alternative:
Only call LoadImageGalleries once per page cycle (in the init).

Instead of clearing the controls and calling LoadGalleryImages again in the same postback (in the button click event), on the button click call a method that iterates through the image controls you already created when LoadGalleryImages was called and adjust them:

1) Remove the onclientclick (clear it out).

2) Attach the event.

Comment: I don't think this will work since the controls are added dynamically. I tried iterating through the page controls and they don't exist since they were added on if(!IsPostBack) { } in OnInit but they aren't there after the page button click. I think it's a necessity to always call _LoadGalleryImages in OnInit so the DOM and page state will be the same each time.

The problem was I wasn't adding IDs to the controls.

Comment: Not sure you understood my response, I didnt' mean only call it once...I meant only call it once per page cycle (in the init).  But as long as the fix worked....Great!

Comment: I see what you mean now. See my solution in the answer.

Comment: I didn't know I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question without waiting 8 hours. See my solution later.

Comment: To funny, ok, will wait to see the answer.

Comment: Take a look at my solution below and see what you think.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the issue can be caused by the fact you haven't set `ID`s of the dynamically created controls. It's quite important, as it's used in the process of firing the post back events. Value of the `ID` for each of the controls should be constant and not change between postbacks.

You can try to modify your `_LoadGalleryImages()` method like this:

```
private void _LoadGalleryImages() {
    PhotoGalleryImageCollection images = PhotoGalleryImages.GetPhotoGalleryImages();

    int imageCtrlCounter = 0;
    foreach(PhotoGalleryImage image in images) {
        ImageButton displayImage = new ImageButton() { ID = String.Format("myDisplayImage{0}", imageCtrlCounter) };
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panelPhotoContainer.Controls.Add(panel);
        displayImage.ImageUrl = "some URL";

        if(!_IsSettingPrimaryPhotoMode) {
            displayImage.OnClientClick = "showPopup(); return false;";
        }
        else {
            displayImage.Command += new CommandEventHandler(displayImage_Command);
            displayImage.CommandName = "ImageButton" + image.PhotoGalleryImageId.ToString();
            displayImage.CommandArgument = image.PhotoGalleryImageId.ToString();
        }

        panel.Controls.Add(displayImage);
        imageCtrlCounter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not setting the IDs was the problem.

Comment: Well it was part of the problem but the solution by @swannee was the complete answer so I marked his the answer but clicked that yours was helpful.

Comment: Oh, I see, I can't see any upvotes on my answer (however, there may be some delay). Anyway, it's good that you fixed it :).

Comment: @Lucas: I would have given you a bump but I've maxed mine for the day...will drop you one tomorrow.

Comment: @swannee: Thanks, since the things you mentioned helped to solve the issue I've given you an upvote as well :).